# Каким образом можно вытащить текст из файла .txt в telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Каким образом можно вытащить текст из .txt и отправить его пользователю? (Pytelegrambotapi)
Текст слишком большой и отправлять его через одну строку не вариант.
Такой код не сработал:

```
with open("blocked.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
```

Comment: Этот код только читает текст из файла. Уточните, что значит "не вариант" и включите код, который отправляет сообщение в своем вопросе.

Comment: Вы можете его как то разбить на части (строки) перед етим надо узнать макс длину сообщения в телеге